# How to wire 220v to 1 ch relay

Tags: ac, relay

I bought the following 1 ch relay - [Link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-Home-DC-12V-220V-10A-1-Ch-315-433MHz-Channel-Wireless-RF-Remote-Control-Transmitter/32782924450.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dd3gVRU) (433 MHz), which is just like the one in this video - [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoEDLP5B5yk).

I want to connect it to my room lightbulb which uses 220v, the thing is I'm not sure how to wire it as you need to connect it with plus and minus.

As far as I'm aware 220v is AC, which means there's no really plus and minus, how do I wire it then? It just doesn't matter? Or is there something else?..

Not really sure about anything I wrote, so take it easy in case I'm wrong, thanks for the help. :]

Comment: People get this wrong a lot, so nothing against you personally, but this is a _relay module_; it's a relay (that little blue box on it) along with some other circuitry to drive it. I could help with a relay alone, but a relay module without any datasheet that I can see is harder to work with.

Comment: @Hearth Yep correct about that, I know there's no datasheet etc, but if you'd have to guess, what would you assume?

Answer (score 1):

The Relay is generally used as a switch in one of the power lines. Both lines could be interrupted as well.

Here's an example. The NPN may be an N-Channel MOSFET as well.
The "220V source" is the 2  wires from your wall outlet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrcsi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately I still couldn't completely understand, and because 220v is something that should be taken seriously, does that mean that it doesn't matter in what way I wire it, it would work either way?

Comment: Yes, breaking one or both lines will work.  In the US, we have a 120V (hot line) and a return (neutral). For safety we would break the hot line.  For us to get 220V we would use 2 hot lines that were on seperate phases.  I don't how the 220V is wire where you are.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Israeli-type-H-plugs-and-socket.jpg This is what it looks like in my country. The bottom one is ground I believe, one is the hotline, and one is neutral(depends on how you wire it), so I just need to connect the hotline and the neutral, correct?

Comment: You can connect just the hotline, leave the other 2 alone.

Comment: Sorry for all the dumb questions, but again I just want to be 100% sure about it, so I have only 1 input cable, and 1 output cable going to the lightbulb, and the other cable is just directly wired to the lightbulb?

Answer (score 0):

This seller's 1st image is wrong. Ignore Firewire and Line Neutral is reversed on INPUT, but for an ungrounded insulated wall light fixture, it won't really matter if you switch line neutral or dual line 240V
.

[image]

[image]

There is a documentation error  on customer [aliexpress site](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-Home-DC-12V-220V-10A-1-Ch-315-433MHz-Channel-Wireless-RF-Remote-Control-Transmitter/32782924450.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dd3gVRU)

If you view the board instead with the Blue relay lettering upside down, you will see the silkscreen in the proper orientation with IN on left and OUT on right.   (Sorry Arabic and Farsi guys but this is the only acceptable orientation in electronics Left-IN to right-OUT.) The Japanese follow this standard perfectly, yet someone inverted it for some reason and screwed it up.

The designer had it correct on the bottom and silkscreen on top.  The 3 screw middle one is open and not used to make it different from the input.

So IGNORE the 1st picture and use the bottom

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO4Y4g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ...what does any of this have to do with firewire? I can only assume that's translation weirdness.

Comment: Agreed, everyone IGNORE the sellers top photo. it has wrong information.  Firewire is what happens if you short Line to Neutral (lol)

Comment: firewire is also an obsolete communications protocol.

Comment: Yes, we used it in the early 90’s for our Apple printer network

Comment: A couple years ago I corrected a, user English manual , in exchange for  a free sample worth 180$  > 3 colour rotating interference laser garden light with rotating motors and diffraction gratings

Comment: I believe Firewire should have been the live wire.